# Always on, SQL Server Enterprise 2022, 3 node cluster: cannot run with only one node up

Tags: sql-server, availability-groups

I have a new 3 node Windows 2022, SQL Enterprise 2022 cluster with file share witness. I am testing this before it goes fullly into production. I was hoping that it would run from only one node, but if I shut two down, no availability groups will start. I even tried changing the quorum and removed the two down nodes, but still I cannot get any AG to start on the one remaining node.

Is this by design? Would I need to evict the other nodes to get the AG roles to start? I can't easily test that as I guess I would need to reseed the other nodes and there are some big databases on there already.

If this is by design, it seems like a flaw. Here I am with one perfectly functioning SQL Server with alll the databases I need but I can't get them on line.

Thanks!

Comment: What is the configured value for `REQUIRED_SYNCHRONIZED_SECONDARIES_TO_COMMIT` (`SELECT name, required_synchronized_secondaries_to_commit FROM sys.availability_groups;`)?

Comment: Hi Dan. All 4 AGs show 0 .

Answer (score 0):

> Is this by design?

Hard to say, there isn't any data right now. What does the cluster log say? Does it say it hit a limit of failures before backing off for a period of time? Is it saying it doesn't have quorum? You'd have to look at the logs to see why it isn't starting up.

You'd need to post the WSFC logs which should be 1 log for each node. You can generate them using PowerShell `Get-ClusterLog -Health -UseLocalTime -Destination C:\SomePathForLogs`

> [...] but if I shut two down, no availability groups will start.

I'd expect the AG to still come online, assuming it's properly configured (WSFC + AG).

> Would I need to evict the other nodes to get the AG roles to start?

Nope.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean. I ran the PowerShell command and all the log files generated just have soon headers for Operational, diagnostic and HealthAgent with no other entries.

Comment: This seems to imply this is by design and a three node cluster will never come on line with only one node up:

Comment: https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/failover-clustering/understanding-quorum-in-a-failover-cluster/ba-p/371678?s=09

Comment: "Having ‘quorum’, or a majority of voters, is based on voting algorithm where more than half of the voters must be online and able to communicate with each other.  Because a given cluster has a specific set of nodes and a specific quorum configuration, the cluster will know how many "votes" constitutes a majority of votes, or quorum.  If the number of voters drop below the majority, the cluster service will stop on the nodes in that group. "

Comment: In my case with three nodes (I have removed the file share witness, so only three nodes to "vote"), a single node is <50% so cluster service stopped. To me this appears to be by design

Comment: See also this MS article: 

WSFC quorum modes & voting configuration - SQL Server Always On | Microsoft Learn

"The absence of a quorum indicates that the cluster is not healthy. Overall WSFC cluster health must be maintained in order to ensure that healthy secondary nodes are available for primary nodes to fail over to. If the quorum vote fails, the WSFC cluster will be set offline as a precautionary measure. This will also cause all SQL Server instances registered with the cluster to be stopped

Comment: Also this MS article: 

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/sql-server/failover-clusters/windows/wsfc-quorum-modes-and-voting-configuration-sql-server?source=recommendations&view=sql-server-ver16

"The absence of a quorum indicates that the cluster is not healthy. Overall WSFC cluster health must be maintained in order to ensure that healthy secondary nodes are available for primary nodes to fail over to. If the quorum vote fails, the WSFC cluster will be set offline as a precautionary measure. This will also cause all SQL Server instances registered with the cluster to be stopped."

Comment: Yes, you need quorum for things to automatically start. It's also possible to force quorum. Again, with the logs in your OP we have no idea the state of the cluster so we couldn't say what the issue was or why it occurred or if that is supposed to happen. If you lost quorum, then yes this is all by design.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that my issue was having a witness added to a three node cluster. This therefore gave four votes. I have since removed the file share witness and now when I repeat the test the cluster will happily run even if only one node is powered on.

Thank you to those that answered my post.

Comment: That's not how it works, FYI. There is dynamic witness which will kick in. The testing methodology is actually flawed as losing 50% or greater will cause quorum loss. By default 3 nodes + witness the witness will not have a vote. Your environment needs to be examined and understood for the issues that you're having, removing the witness is more of a symptom of a larger issue that the issue itself.

Comment: Thanks a lot Sean. Have realised eventually that the issue was the AG's in SQL had one node configured as manual failover. So failover to that node could never occur by using FCM but works just fine with SSMS.

Comment: You should never fail over an AG using failover cluster manager (FCM) or PowerShell commands to move a group as this will have a chance to cause SQL and the cluster to get metadata out of sync.